# Which Ubuntu variant is recommended for an eee PC with a single-core Atom and 1GB RAM?

Tags: software-recommendation, eeepc

I have an Asus EEE PC with a 1ghz intel atom processor and 1 gb ram with a 170gb hard drive. Which would run better ubuntu xubuntu or lubuntu? i had ubuntu for a few moments and it was really laggy and unresponsive.

Answer (score 3):

I have an Asus EEE PC 1000H (1.6 GHz Atom, 1GB RAM, 160GB HD), which is very similar to yours and can say that Xubuntu works *very well*. I'd recommend it for anything running one of the older single-core Atoms (N230, N270, etc.).

- Firefox works great, although if you save and restore entire sessions, it takes a few seconds (10-15) to exit or open and restore the sessions.
- Youtube works well, 480p and even some 720p videos play smoothly.
- The usual office apps (I installed LibreOffice) work well.

Answer (score 1):

Complete benchmark between KDE, GNOME, XFCE and LXDE:

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_desktop_vitals&num=1

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the use of your machine.
Check out this link, will help you in deciding http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/whichbuntu

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have a smaller eee, 512MB RAM and 8GB disk - IIRC it's an old celeron CPU.  I ran EasyPeasy on it at the moment and it runs really well. (thought the info might give you a low benchmark)

Answer (score 0):

For real speed install openbox or fluxbox.  Very lightweight.  They don't have a variant.

Comment: What do you mean when you say they "don't have a variant"? Lubuntu uses `openbox` as its window manager. Do you mean there's no variant of Ubuntu whose GUI is pure X + openbox?